# how to check a construct of javascript

Tags: javascript, this

i have a function fn() which is reutrning this keyword see below

```
function fn()
{
  return this;
}
log( fn() === function, "The context is the global object." );
//ERROR Unexpected token

log( fn() === this, "The context is the global object." );
//true
```

i have a question fn() === function why it is not true?? fn() and function are same type
and fn() === this is true?? while fn() and this are not of same type

if i do this

```
function fn(){
  //return this;
}
```

then result is false. it means fn()=== this this condition is comparing this to fn() return.

Comment: `this` is global object(implemented as windows). So comparing `this == this` will anyway results `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to check `typeof`

```
function fn() {
    return this;
}
console.log((typeof (fn) == "function"), "The context is the global object.");
// true, "The context is the global object." 

console.log(fn() === this, "The context is the global object.");
// true "The context is the global object."
```

So,

1. `fn() ===  "function" --> false`. Because `fn()` returns `window object` and you are comparing it with string `"function"`.
2. `fn() === this --- > true` because `this` (owner of function i.e `window`) and global object `this (window)` are equal.

Comment: @user13500 yup `typeof` returns string

Comment: @Pilot— *this* is not [context](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10), it's a [keyword](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.1). A function's *this* keyword defaults to the global object if not set by the call. If not set in strict mode, it will be *undefined*.

Comment: @RobG 100 % agreed but this depends on context as well

Comment: @Pilot— *this* is one parameter of an execution context, it is not a "context" itself in any meaning of the word.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to determine the type, try the typeof operator

```
console.log( typeof(fn) === 'function' ? 'Its a function' : 'Its NOT a function' );
```

From what I understand, the 'this' that you're returning from fn() is a Window object and not the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
function fn()
{
  return this;
}

console.log((fn() === function)); 
// the output of function is trying to be compared with the function 
// declaration... you can't do that... you need to compare against a value

console.log((typeof fn === 'function'));
// the type of fn itself,  not its return value, is the string 'function', 
// therefore it is true

console.log((fn() === this));
//the return value of the function is this... this is the window object and 
// this exists, therefore this is true
```